# MySQL: how to make this query involving a join and a left join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, outer-join

This is just a college exercise, so I'm not in a hurry. But I'd like to have the answer already. Consider these tables and rows:

```
create table course (
    numco   integer,
    nameco  varchar(20) not null,
    primary key (numco)
);
create table prereq (
    numco integer,
    numcoprereq integer,
    primary key (numco, numcoprereq),
    foreign key (numco) references course (numco),
    foreign key (numcoprereq) references course (numco)
);
insert into course values (1, 'course 1');
insert into course values (2, 'course 2');
insert into course values (3, 'course 3');
insert into course values (4, 'course 4');
insert into course values (1, 'course 5');
insert into course values (2, 'course 6');
insert into prereq values (4, 2);
insert into prereq values (2, 1);
```

I did not made this. I just translated it and removed some irrelevant bits. I know there are two `course` rows with the same PK, but I'll have to ask my teacher on this one.

He asked us to write a query to obtain the names of the courses and the names of the course's prerequisites. If it was just the course's number, a left join would do the trick. But I can't make it work with the names. It should output:

```
course 1    (null)
course 2    course 1
course 3    (null)
course 4    course 2
course 5    (null)
course 6    course 1
```

I searched a lot and wrote two attempts:

```
select C1.nameco, C2.nameco as namecoprereq
    from course C2 left join
    (course C1 join prereq P on C1.numco = P.numco)
    on C2.numco = P.numcoprereq;

select C1.nameco, C2.nameco as namecoprereq
    from (course C1 join prereq P on C1.numco = P.numco)
    left join course C2 on C2.numco = P.numcoprereq;
```

They output, respectively:

```
course 2    course 1
course 6    course 1
course 4    course 2
(null)      course 3
(null)      course 4
course 2    course 5
course 6    course 5
course 4    course 6
```

and

```
course 2    course 1
course 2    course 5
course 4    course 2
course 4    course 6
course 6    course 1
course 6    course 5
```

I know (I guess, I haven't tried) I could do it with union and minus, but I want to know if it's possible to do it on a single select. Any idea on how to do that without kludging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly have the right answer with your queries, but I think your searching a little to far. Just think of it in "english" :

1. I have courses (`FROM course`)
2. Some of them have prerequisites (`LEFT JOIN prereq`)
3. I need the name of the prerequisite (`LEFT JOIN course`)

This should work :

```
SELECT
    c1.nameco,
    c2.nameco AS nameprereq
FROM course AS c1
LEFT JOIN prereq AS p ON p.numcoprereq = c1.numco
LEFT JOIN course AS c2 ON c2.numco = p.numco
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you got it backwards. On the `ON` clauses, switch the `p.` attributes. That's the answer I wanted. It never occurred to me to use two left joins. I'd like to know in more detail how are those queries executed to know why my attempts didn't worked. Thanks again for the answer.